# React dev tools auto selecting parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

Using version 4.3.0 of react dev tools the problem is consistent on chrome and firefox.

I have a react admin component rendering child components of various buttons and track names, this is a playlist app.

My problem is that when I try to inspect a child component, react dev tools automatically selects the parent component back on what seems to me as rerender.

So I can only see the props of the child comp for a very brief time, I can barely press "print comp to console" until react dev tool automatically selects the parent.

I'm using react-router-dom and firebase

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is trivial

Alexandre

here is a screenshot : [gif](https://gph.is/g/aKN908o)

Comment: Noticed there are some errors in your console and increased during your operation.

Comment: The errors is due to lack of connection shouldn't be a problem, however I'm getting a " backend.js:6 Could not find Fiber with id "1077" " warning which might be the cause of this?